# JS: add onclick function to table cell

Tags: javascript, html-table, onclick, addition

I've created a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/n2r5t91v/

```js
var myvalue = 20 // abbreviating how I calculate myvalue
var cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'addToCell(' + myvalue + ');');

function addToCell(value) {
  var td_cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
  td_cell.value = td_cell.value + ' ' + value;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="mytd">
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect the value of that `<td>` cell to change from "test" to "test 20" upon clicking. Why doesn't it work like this?

Comment: Stackoverflow has the same functionality as jsfiddle, please post your code here so we do not have to go to another site. The snipplet button when you create/edit the question is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this way. There's no `value` attribute for `<td>`. Use `innerHTML`:

```js
var myvalue = 20;
var cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'addToCell(' + myvalue + ');');

function addToCell(value) {
  var td_cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
  td_cell.innerHTML = td_cell.innerHTML + ' ' + value;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="mytd">
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also do in a different way in this part:

```
td_cell.innerHTML += ' ' + value;
```

Comment: There is value attribute on TD: look `<td value="20">`. Now there is attribute. Better to say property.

Comment: @dfsq Sure, will rewrite it.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry I am not sure. Where exactly is `value` in `<td>` in the question?

Comment: I tried it with `.innerHTML` on jsfiddle.net and it didn't work there. when I use "run code snippet" on stackoverflow it works and also in my html file it works. Thanks!

Comment: @user3182532 and if you read my answer, you will learn why it does not work on jsFiddle.

Comment: @user3182532 Awesome. JSFiddle needs tweaking. Better to use JSBin or your own HTML. Read epascarello's answer for why it doesn't work. Please do accept my answer in 5 mins.

Comment: @user3182532 Read epascarello's answer, it has proper explanation. Strange that someone downvoted it, in fact it's the best and the most complete answer for your question.

Comment: @dfsq Looks like all the answers in this question are downvoted! :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it does not work is the jsfiddle is set to run onload so the code actually looks like

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var myvalue = 20 // abbreviating how I calculate myvalue
  var cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
  cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'addToCell(' + myvalue + ');');

  function addToCell (value) {
    var td_cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
    td_cell.value = td_cell.value + ' ' + value;
  }
})
```

Now since you are adding the event in a bad way (using attributes) the function execute in global scope. So the function that is defined inside of the onload method can not be seen by the click handler.

So you either need to set the JavaScript to run at the bottom of the body (jsFiddle Settings), you need to make the function global, or best solution, bind the event the correct way with addEventListener.

And inputs do not have a value, they have HTML and text. So it needs to be innerHTML.

```
  var myvalue = 20 // abbreviating how I calculate myvalue
  var cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
  cell.addEventListener('click', function () { addToCell(myvalue); });

  function addToCell(value){
    var td_cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
    td_cell.innerHTML = td_cell.innerHTML + ' ' + value;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think I have the background to understand your answer, I tried to read it multiple times. I don't know what you mean by "is set to run onload" and what do you mean by "the function (which one? sounds like there's some "onload-function"? or do you mean addToCell?) executes in global scope" ?

Comment: Click the cog wheel on the jsfiddle. It has modes on how the code runs. The default is the code runs on window onload.

Comment: Since you add the attribute the onclick fires the code in the scope of the document. So it looks at global scope for the event. Since the event is defined inside the onload method, it is not visible to the outside. Basic concept of scope.

Answer (score -2):

Try With This

```
var myvalue = 20 // abbreviating how I calculate myvalue
var cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
//cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'addToCell(' + myvalue + ');');
cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addToCell(myvalue);
    });
function addToCell(value){
var td_cell = document.getElementById("mytd");
td_cell.innerHTML = td_cell.innerHTML + ' ' + value;
}
```

Comment: Explain, do not just say "try this"